# How to run xampp control panel in the Xubuntu

Tags: xampp, xubuntu

How can I start xampp? After the installation there was no shortcut created on the desktop, now I am unable to find it. I am using the latest XAMPP for latest xubuntu.

Comment: Did you look in the menu?  If it's there, you can pin it to the desktop or system tray as a shortcut.

Answer (score -1):

TRy this option it worked for me. Type this command on terminal     sudo -s -H 
than enter your root password then type this command   opt/lampp/lampp start

Comment: (1) Please just [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1454167/edit) you first answer; don’t post a new answer just to issue a correction.  (2) You normally need to enter ***your (own) user password** (and not the root password)* when you run `sudo`.